# How to deploy a java jar file to remote server through maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I want to deploy a jar file to a remote server and run it. Is there a plugin for maven can do this process? I know that tomcat for maven plugin can deploy the war file to remote server, but my project is not a servlet project. I think the process is that:
     1. transfer the jar file to remote server.
     2. ran the jar file.

What is a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: You could check http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ssh-external.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A combination of these two questions will probably be what you need:

[Maven copy local file to remote server using SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/909867/79450)

[Run remote command via ssh using Maven3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12412519/79450)